# Question about multiplying columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I was wondering if it was possible to multiply two columns and if so how would this take place

Suppose I have a table

```
a    b
1    4
2    5
3    6
```

Could I do something like

```
SELECT a *b from table
```

Would this multiply the contents row by row then store it in a new column

Are these result right

```
4
10
18
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That query would multiply the values, but it wouldn't "store it in a new column"  To store it you would have to issue an update statement.

Assuming you add a new column ("c") to your table you could do:

```
update table 
  set c = a * b
```

If all you need is the new column in a result set, without modifying the underlying table you could:

```
select a, b, (a*b) as c from table
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can perfectly do that.

**update**

To clarify: The query and output you mentioned in your question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing a calculated column in a base table, consider a viewed table:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT a, b, 
       a * b AS my_calc
  FROM MyTable;
```